# Reload/Refresh template

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Olá, estou carregando minha view com um timer e cada vez que timer é executado não limpa a tela e sim adiciona os mesmos itens novamente.
Já tentei cache=false, window.reload, state.reload, state.go, mas sem resultados, meu codigo:

```
lista = function () {
    $http.post(G.URL + 'pagina.jsp')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.totalItens = response.data.records.length;
            $scope.items = response.data.records;
            $scope.counter = 1;
        }, function (error) { $scope.items = "Não foi possível listar."; });
}
$interval(function () {
    $scope.counter += 1;
    if ($scope.counter > 59) {
        $scope.counter = 1;
        lista()
        //$ionicHistory.clearCache([$state.current.name]).then(function () { $state.reload(); });
    }
}, 1000);
$scope.$watch(function () { return $scope.d = { tempo: $scope.counter }; }, true);
```

Agradeço de antemão.

Comment: Pela sua lógica do `$interval` o usuário precisa esperar 60 segundos para carregar a nova lista de `$scope.items`.

Comment: Vc viu se o seu response.data.records está vindo certo. Se estiver coloque $scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.items = response.data.records; }); no lugar de $scope.items = response.data.records; . Se não der certo coloque também seu html na sua pergunta para vermos se tem algo errado.

Comment: Obrigado Never e André, consegui resolver usando angular.extend($scope e $timeout no final e fez a atualização das variaveis na tela como eu precisava, obrigado mesmo pela atenção.